# The proof/reasoning for $A = [A_1 A_2]$ is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a theorem I do not have an idea how to prove that.

> Theorem: If $A_{1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ has orthonormal
>   columns, then there *exists* $A_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (n-r)}$
>   such that $A = [A_1 A_2]$ is orthogonal.

Any idea to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just have to apply [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to extend the columns of $A_1$ to form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The additional vectors that are found using this procedure are used to form $A_2$.